# Video tag not showing source video on chrome android

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a .webm video that I am dynamically setting as the source for the video tag.

```
vidPlayer = document.getElementById("player");
vidPlayer.src = videoPath;
```

The corresponding HTML:

```
<body>
    <video id="player" class="video-player"></video>
</body>
```

This is working perfectly on the web browser but when I view this on my mobile, I get a white screen.
I checked the elements tab in the developer tools if different HTML was getting rendered, but it wasn't.
However, in the network tab for chrome web, there is a call made to fetch the video but the same does not happen for chrome android.
I am running this code on localhost.
Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong or why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, if your video does not have controls enabled, then for mobile browsers, the user must interact(tap or swipe on the screen) for the video to be visible on the screen.
With controls enabled the video is visible from the start.